# Change language programmatically after login

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I have a multilingual site and I want to change the language programmatically after user login to his own language to see all the content in his language.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should not be necessary to do it from code, as one of the settings present in admin/config/regional/language/configure allows to set the language to the one selected from the users in their user profile settings.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: And you can also define your own language negotiation plugins if you have some custom logic, see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5164/use-another-language-than-default-as-standard